# Adding bytes from a DB array causes overflow. How to get the actual value?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, byte, sasm

The problem I am facing is trying to add all the bytes defined in
`data db 0x00,0x10,0x20,0x30,0x40,0x50,0x60,0x70,0x80,0x90`.
I want to average them, which means dividing the sum by 10.

```
%include "io.inc"

SECTION .text

global CMAIN

CMAIN:

mov ebp, esp                      ; for correct debugging
SUB AX, AX                        ; clear the register AX
MOV ECX, 0x000A                   ; set counter to 10
MOV ESI, 0                        ; set offset to 0

AW:                               ; Destination of Loop AW as long as counter != 0
                                  
ADD AL,[ds:data + ESI]            ; Add data in the data array into AL
ADD ESI, 1                        ; Increase ESI and move along the data array
LOOP AW                           ; Loop to label AW,CX=CX-1 Keep looping until CX= 0


SUB EDX, EDX                      ; Clear EDX
MOV CX, 0x000A                    ; Set the divider to 10 data
DIV CX                            ; Divide AX with CX, AX = AX / 10
MOV [ds:result], EAX              ; The result is stored into location pointed by result
PRINT_HEX 4, result               ; Display "result" in the output window
    ret                           ; end program

SECTION .data

data db 0x00,0x10,0x20,0x30,0x40,0x50,0x60,0x70,0x80,0x90
result db 0x0
```

I have tried, and this is the closest I can get. Initially I used EAX instead of AL (I took the 8 least significant bits), and the values I got were very huge and not in the least want I expected.

I add all the values together but it overflows and results in a
value of 14 instead of the correct value of 0x48. I am wondering if there is a way to add byte data without causing overflow? Or is this just the limitation of the assembly? Or I am dumb?

Comment: You can either manually propagate carry, e.g. by `adc ah, 0` or extend the value first before using a 16 bit addition, e.g. `movzx dx, [data+esi]; add ax, dx`

Comment: This is NASM, so `data` doesn't magically imply an operand size.  `movzx edx, byte [data + esi]` / `add eax,edx`.  Just like you'd get from compiler output summing an array of `unsigned char` into an `int total`; look at compiler output on https://godbolt.org/

Comment: The reason your values were huge when using `eax` instead of `al` was because loading any `e??` register with a value from memory will fetch four bytes in a row, starting at the memory address in brackets, and load it into your destination as though it were a 32-bit number. So for example if you did `mov eax,[data]` you would load `eax` with `0x30201000`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> data db 0x00,0x10,0x20,0x30,0x40,0x50,0x60,0x70,0x80,0x90
> result db 0x0
> ```

The array contains byte-sized values, so logically the average of these values will fit in the byte-sized *result* variable, and you can perform the calculation using the byte-sized division that divides AX by the number of elements.

Don't use the slow `loop` instruction! And since you already are using an offset in the array, use the value from the offset to control the loop:

```
  xor   ebx, ebx                      ; Offset
  xor   eax, eax                      ; Sum
AW:
  movzx ecx, byte [ds:data + ebx]     ; Load element
  add   eax, ecx
  inc   ebx
  cmp   ebx, 10
  jb    AW
```

Now perform the byte-sized division. You have a suitable divider (**10**) in the BL register:

```
  div   bl                            ; AX / BL
  mov   [ds:result], al
```

---

If the data were a bit more random, then you would appreciate some rounding for that average. Next methods work for any array with at most 255 byte-sized elements:

- Before division: adding half of the denominator (BX) to the nominator (AX).

  ```
  mov   cx, bx
  shr   cx, 1
  add   ax, cx
  div   bl                            ; AX / BL
  mov   [ds:result], al
  ```
- After division: incrementing the quotient (AL) if double of the remainder (AH) is greater than the denominator (BX).

  ```
  div   bl                            ; AX / BL
  movzx cx, ah
  shl   cx, 1
  cmp   cx, bx
  cmc
  adc   al, 0
  mov   [ds:result], al
  ```

Comment: Just to explain why `loop` is slow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently
It's fine on a 16-bit x86 CPU but shouldn't be used on 32-bit or higher architectures.